# Is there any way to determine trigger source, whether manual build or scm change?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a job on Jenkins.

When i click manual build now, it is building.
When triggered from a git commit, it is also building.

How to determine trigger source, whether manual build or scm change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a condition to your Jenkins job to figure out who is executing the job right now, if it's the SCM or a manual build.

[image]

In the **build cause** you have a list of options which you can later on get as parameter in the job.

use it to determine who is the initiator of the build.

Comment: can you tell me how will i get these conditional steps on jenkins

Comment: Install this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

Comment: Thanks i got it.Is there any script also i have to write under "Steps to run if condition is met" which i m getting this option just below the Exclusive cause.?

Comment: in Run when i am selecting Build Cause from drop down list in the next line Build cause option is appearing.Now in the Build Cause i am selecting either User Cause  or SCM trigger.is it same as you suggested to identify which is triggering?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need it for the api exposes that information. So you can just hit the url [jenkins]/job/[jobname]/[buildNum]/api/[xml|json] and there is a causes node that lists what triggered the build.